# redefining a constant in C

Tags: c

If I have a constant defined as such in a header file:

```
#define MY_CONSTANT 1
```

And I include a library to the whole project which includes a different definition for the same constant:

```
#define MY_CONSTANT 0
```

I naturally get conflicts while compiling. Supposing that I cannot alter my project code and that I can only change my library code, what can I do to make MY_CONSTANT as defined by my lib?

EDIT:
just to clarify, my goal is to update a constant in my code through a library. Because I'm writing a library to simulate hardware functions, I have to go by the rule that the software itself must be untouched. There is a loop of sort in the main file that uses the constant. I need to change this constant, but without actually altering it in the main file.

Comment: did you mean `#define MY_CONSTANT 1` (without semicolon)?

Comment: this is almost certainly not your code. Please show us the real thing.

Comment: @Vlad, probably not with `=` either.

Comment: Is it a constant, or do you want it to have different values at different points in the code?

Comment: Can't you simply rename your MY_CONSTANT and thus avoid this conflict altogether or what is your goal? Do you want this constant to have your value in the library?

Comment: yes w/o the semicolon. and there is not much I can show besides this since my main code has a loop that runs off MY_CONSTANT. I can't adjust MY_CONSTANT in my main code, only through my library. So I think that any additional code is unnecessary.

Comment: looks like I'm too trigger happy with typing code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can undefine the other definition

```
#ifdef MY_CONSTANT
#undef MY_CONSTANT
#endif
#define MYCONSTANT 0
```

Also, you should remove the `=`, and the `;`

P.S. as mentioned, it will not change the code that already compiled.

Comment: I compile the lib and the main code together, so i'll try that

Comment: so looks like what happens is that my included static lib gets compiled first :O. So all this undef just doesn't work....

Comment: @mugetsu Your included static libs are already compiled, they are only linked when you build it.

Comment: then is it possible for the compiler to ignore the conflict when the main file is compiled? Since I already have the constant defined as I want it.

Comment: Just make sure your definition comes after the one from the header file, and use the method I showed above.

Answer (score 4):

You can `#undef MY_CONSTANT` and redefine to the value you want, but that's just asking for trouble. See if you can modify the design entirely so that `MY_CONSTANT`s don't clash.

Answer (score 4):

Undef, redef, and then redef it back

```
#ifdef MY_CONSTANT
#undef MY_CONSTANT
#endif
#define MY_CONSTANT 0

/* code here */

#undef MY_CONSTANT /* not needed if you don't need the library's definition*/
#include "library.h" /* file that originally defined it
                        might not work if include guards prevent it
                        in that case #undef LIBRARY_H
                        although that causes more trouble :( */
```

Comment: I have a static library that I added to the project to compile with, so it seems like MY_CONSTANT gets defined first in my lib and then in my main file, which creates a contradiction since I can't use undef in my main file.