# Is it erroneous to reuse #define for the same identifier in c?

Tags: c, macros, kernighan-and-ritchie

The K&R book author says that

> A second #define for the same identifier is erroneous unless the
> second token sequence is identical to the first.

But when i tried , the compiler didn't raise any error.
So, Can you please elaborate what does the author want to say?

Comment: What compiler are you using? Gcc, clang and msvc will raise a warning about this.

Comment: See [redefining a constant in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8159256/3422102)

Comment: @BillLynch I am using GCC.

Comment: `gcc` won't raise an "error", but it will issues a "warning". Compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and if you redefine a constant without undefining it first you will receive, e.g.  `"warning: "ABC" redefined"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did what you say you did, it very much *should* have raised an diagnostic message. From the relevant section, `C11 6.10.3 Macro replacement`:

> Two replacement lists are identical if and only if the preprocessing tokens in both have the same number, ordering, spelling, and white-space separation, where all white-space separations are considered identical.
>
> An identifier currently defined as an object-like macro shall not be redefined by another `#define` preprocessing directive unless the second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two replacement lists are identical. Likewise, an identifier currently defined as a function-like macro shall not be redefined by another `#define` preprocessing directive unless the second definition is a function-like macro definition that has the same number and spelling of parameters, and the two replacement lists are identical.

See, for example, the following transcript:

```sh
pax:/paxhome> cat prog.c
#define X 7
#define X 99

int main(void) { return 99; }

pax:/paxhome> gcc --std=c17 prog.c -o prog
prog.c:2: warning: "X" redefined
    2 | #define X 99
      |
prog.c:1: note: this is the location of the previous definition
    1 | #define X 7
      |
```

Keep in mind the definition of "identical" given in that first paragraph, they don't have to be exactly the same on a character by character basis. The following two can be considered identical based on the rules given:

```c
#define X 7 + 2
#define X \
    7 \
        + \
            2
```

Also keep in mind that `gcc` is treating this as a warning rather than an error. The standard itself only states that a *diagnostic* message must be generated for invalid programs but also contains the following footnote (my emphasis):

> Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a *valid* program is still correctly translated. It *may* also successfully translate an *invalid* program.

So `gcc` is within its rights to simply warn you but compile the program anyway.
If you wanted to treat warnings as errors (which is something I tend to prefer for my own code), you can always add the `-Werror` flag to your compile command (or possibly `-Wpedantic -pedantic-errors`, depending on your needs).